# Which editor and debugger for typescript

Tags: debugging, ide, typescript

I am working on a nodejs project in which all code is written in typescript. It follows a microservice pattern (and each microservice is an independent project) hence lot of projects needs to be opened and debugged at the same time.

I tried webstorm and visual studio (with NTVS) but not satisified with both of them. Webstorm ignores many build errors (very important as those will fail during CI) and not as good as visual studio in intellisense and ease of use. On the other hand, Visualstudio is not as fast as I want. Also I am tied to windows and the filename length problem in node_modules is very frequent and annoying.

Others (atom, VSCode) doesn't have typescript debug support (or am I missing something?).

Can you please share your experience? Also I was wondering which editor google developers might be using to develop angular 2 :)

Comment: I am using VS Code for quite a while now - and I am loving it. It is simple and lightweight and I don't miss the heavier Visual Studio Editor!

I do all my development in a Debian Virtual machine (because PM2 is super useful in Linux world and I have to stick to Windows as my primary OS) - I open the projects I want to debug in VS Code and use PM2 to run rest of the apps.

Comment: Here my help for Debugging Angular 2 in VSCode ;-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495655/how-to-debug-angular-with-vscode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working on a TypeScript project for 1.5 years now and am quite happy with using Visual Studio because we used .NET for back-end stuffs. For myself I consider the speed as "Ok", it is not that good - but the other stuffs e.g. intellisense is what we really like. I also personally think that as a "son" of Microsoft, TypeScript will get the best support from its "cousin" - Visual Studio.

However if you are a Eclipse person, you may be interested in this TypEcs (http://typecsdev.com/). There was also a post by Steve Fenton talking about TypeScript IDEs you may be interested (https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201409/Blog/Which-TypeScript-IDE/), he listed a few of the popular ones with a few sentences of comments, including Atom and the atom-typescript extension.

Comment: VS support for TypeScript has a lot of issues, such as ignoring `tsconfig.json` files in favor of VS project files, etc. NuGet is also buggy. Not recommended, even VS Code is better.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the conversation.

I recently tried VisualStudio 2015, VisualStudio Code 0.9, Atom (with [Atom-Typescrip](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript)t package). And quite comfortable with Atom.

Atom-TypeScript uses the latest version of TypeScript so you can use all new features like async/await, string interpolation etc. The package created by community so we don't need to wait for major IDE release to use new TypeScript features.

For debugging couldn't find one. But love to use [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector) for its light weight. The problem is you need to debug it in javascript version not in typescript version. Not so sure but maybe if you can provide map file you can debug the typescript version? like we have on Google Chrome Inspector.

Comment: It'd be hard to feel content debugging without source maps, vendor black-boxing, an inspector, conditional breakpoints and step debugging. [`atom-typescript`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) could be made better with `node-inspector` integration. But it's been 4 years since the idea was proposed and the [related issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/316) to integrate debugging hasn't garnered much interest unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

VSCode can debug in Node. No browser debugging yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not a recommendation, but I suggest you do not buy JetBrains' products (IntelliJ/WebStorm/ReSharper) for TypeScript editing unless you have evaluated them properly.

They reused a lot of their own logic for other languages instead of taking full benefit of the TypeScript language service, which means they behave more like a fancy JavaScript editor that can make some clever guesses as opposed to a robust IDE for a statically typed langauge. (Their type inference is different from the compiler and may fool you into believing an untyped expression (implicit `any`) is well-typed. Also, all the refactoring are the same as the JS ones, so they do not use or preserve any type information. No type-information-based refactoring (like safe renaming and moving) are available either.)

As for debugging, you may have more milage debugging the generated JS. Not only is it well supported, it also reveals problems that occur in compiler-inserted code. The latter would be otherwise difficult to understand if you're only looking at the TypeScript source. Also, in the generated code, you can actually set break points in single line lambda function bodies.

Comment: Webstorm rename seems to be correct in a simple test with shadowing.

Comment: Try renaming anything exported, it soon becomes an interactive string replacement instead of anything intelligent.

Answer (score 0):

I too use Visual Studio. I haven't had any problem with its speed; I find everything is as immediate as I expect it too.

However, I haven't been using "TypeScript" projects. I have been using generic "Web" projects with TypeScript files. Plus, I don't use Visual Studio's own building and compilation facilities; I use my own Gulp tasks for my project (including rebuilding, watching for saves, minification, testing, etc), and [Task Runner Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) to manage/run them from inside Visual Studio. I think it's the best of both worlds: the snappiness and features of Visual Studio, and the flexibility of running my own custom tasks independent of platform.

I have to admit I don't do any deep debugging (e.g. breakpoints, stepping) from the IDE. Does VS do that with TypeScript? If I catch an error during execution (in the browser), I always have my source maps indicating where the error is, so I go back to the code, attempt to fix it, save, and reload in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VSCode to actively debug an angular/node/typescript application.  It does work, but you will need to do some setup/configuration.  You must tell VSCode how to debug your applications.  For instance I have multiple options in my launch.json configuration to debug my gulp scripts, my node server.js file, and the angular/typescript application via chrome using the "Debugger for Chrome" extension installed in VSCode.  It is all possible with some configuration. Finally, depending on your exact situation you may need to have and correctly configure the map files for your project from javascript to typescript.

I also had the problem of file paths too long in the node_modules folder in visual studio when opening a project with npm.  This is due to Visual Studio trying to download all your packages - incorrectly so I might add.  The only way to avoid this for my project was to mark the node_modules folder as a hidden folder in windows (top level only).