# TypeScript debugging on Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, typescript, atom-editor

A year ago it was asked about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000677/which-editor-and-debugger-for-typescript), so I am wondering what the situation is now in regards to code/debug TypeScript on Linux.

The [Atom TypeScript plugin](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) seams really good, but I can't find a single post about debugging in Firefox or Chrome on Linux.

**Question**

Does someone know what the state is for TypeScript debugging on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug TypeScript in Chrome using [JavaScript Source Maps](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps). It can be generated by TypeScript compiler. [Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-using-cross-browser-source-maps--cms-24430) you can find tutorial.

You can also verify debugging support in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript
package for Atom editor. It should be cool setting the breakpoints.

Note the load time of the Atom editor will increase a bit after installing this plugin.

The plugin has great potential and great features list.
Atom is like HTML page.
You can understand this if you go **View->Developer->Toggle Developer Tools** .