# Chrome Debugger not working vscode angular 5

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im trying to use the google chrome debugger and everytime i press the debug button I get cannot reach localhost? what am I doing wrong?

my launch.json is set up like this...

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
          "url": "http://localhost:1234",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "attach",
          "name": "Attach to Chrome",
          "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
      ]
    }
```

[image]

any help would be appreciated and please let me know if more info is needed..

Comment: Clicking debug will initate the debugger to connect to you dev server, it won't start the server itself. You need to run `npm start` first then only after the app is running you click the debug button.

Comment: My server is running, I have started it using ng serve

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question, are you able to browse to `http://localhost:1234`? Perhaps you can also try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Check the port in the `package.json` start script : ng serve -p <port>... is it 1234 ?

Comment: follow this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495655/how-to-debug-angular-with-vscode