# How can I debug an Angular 6 App?

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging

currently I have a problem with one angular 6 App. I use the [Fuse](http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/apps/dashboards/analytics) Skeleton Template for it. Currently I'm getting trouble, when I try to use MatSnackBar in the App. As soon as I add the MatSnackBar to the constructor of a component, I get an Error in the JS Console of the Browser.

```
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private location: Location,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar
  )
  {

  }
```

And this is the Error message:

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
```

How can I get more Information what is wrong?

Comment: is that the complete error log?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import MatSnackBarModule in app.module.ts array.

```
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material';

imports: [ ... MatSnackBarModule ...
```

Without it, I get an error just like you

To debug, if you have access to the imported source code(and use vscode), follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495655/how-to-debug-angular-with-vscode) instructions, put a break point on the constructor of the imported class.

You could also put a **debugger** and open the Developer tools(F12 in chrome):

```
foo() { 
   debugger; 
   console.log('footest');
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a open source plugin available for google chrome, So you can use the AngularJS Batarang

[chrome plugin for debug AngularJS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)