# How to debug an Angular CLI app with the custom webpack builder?

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-code

I built a repo to expose my issue: https://github.com/franklin626/custom_webpack_undebuggable

This Angular CLI app has a custom webpack setup (`webpack.config.js`). It also has a `.vscode/launch.json` configuration to debug from VS Code upon either `ng test` (unit tests) or `ng serve`. I can place breakpoints for my unit tests, but not when running `ng serve`:

In my debug tab in VS Code, I run my "launch Chrome" routine followed by "attach localhost". I place a breakpoint on `other.component.ts:14`, and browse to *localhost:4200/othermodule* to fire up my lazy loaded module `OtherModule` containing `OtherComponent`.

I can't place a breakpoint on `home.component.ts:13` either, even though it is in the default module.

[image]

[image: HomeComponent in AppModule]

[image: OtherComponent in OtherModule]

**VS Code complains the breakpoint can't be hit and suggests a possible problem with source maps. I can see the original sources are loaded in the browser though. What is going on ?**

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/woy4MXn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial#_debugging-angular) guide works for me with your repo, latest vscode and debugger for chrome.
Please see the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDVMe.jpg) and follow these steps:

- Install [debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)
- Create .vscode/launch.json with the following content

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
   {
     "type": "chrome",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
     "url": "http://localhost:4200",
     "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
   }
 ]
}
```

- Set a breakpoint in Home or Other component
- Press F5 to start the debugger

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's the most canonical for other users in the future.

Answer (score 4):

you can add `.vscode/tasks.json` with label `debug` as follow

it will start build, launch chrome debug and watch for changes

tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "debug",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start",
      "isBackground": true,
      "presentation": {
        "focus": true,
        "panel": "dedicated"
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "source": "ts",
        "applyTo": "closedDocuments",
        "fileLocation": [
          "relative",
          "${cwd}"
        ],
        "pattern": "$tsc",
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": {
            "regexp": "(.*?)"
          },
          "endsPattern": {
            "regexp": "Compiled |Failed to compile."
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

and modify `.vscode/launch.json` to use `debug` task as preLaunchTask

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Chrome debug",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "debug",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

also move package to devDependencies

```
npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack
```

pull request

```
https://github.com/franklin626/custom_webpack_undebuggable/pull/2
```

Comment: Awarding bounty as this answer was the most practical, it turns out VS Code was creating my .vscode folder in the wrong place...

Comment: Appreciated the solution with background! This is also the best answer for this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42495655/5770014)